# Dropdown won't populate with Javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate `select box` using below script, it does populate it in the background but I cannot see the changes in the page. The only thing I can see in the `DropDownList` is the item I add manually. Can you see something wrong here?

**EDIT:** I can see that it runs without an error from the console, it adds the options and increases the length of select box. The problem is they do not reflect in the list.

I am not using localhost, do you think it can affect such a script?

```
<body onload="init('map');loadlist();">
    <div id="map" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#999999;">
        <div id="right-container">
            <div class="input-group" style="float:left; margin-bottom:10px;">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Navteq POI'leri</span>
                <select id="navteq-select" data-placeholder="POI Katmanı Yok" multiple onchange="visualiseNavteqPOIs();" class="form-control header-select">
                    <option value="6512">Alışveriş</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8">
            function loadlist(){
            $.get('http://api.visiothink.com/v1/query/categories?key=XXX').done(function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data).response;

                var dropdown = document.getElementById("navteq-select");
                for (i = 0; i < data.all.length; i++) { 
                    var o = data.all[i];

                    if (dropdown) {
                        console.log('Populating for '+ o.name);

                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.text = o.name;
                        option.value = o.categoryId;
                        dropdown.add(option);
                    }
                }
                console.log(dropdown.options.length);
            });
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you see a valid response when you go to http://api.visiothink.com/v1/query/categories?key=XXX or does your console say that `data.all.length` is undefined?

Comment: Yeah, I get valid response. I can see the addition of options and length increase in the console, but I can't see them in the list itself.

Comment: What's a valid key for the request?

Comment: Your code [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/ybqse8L3/), there's has to be something wrong in the JSON string.

Comment: I am not sure I am allowed to share that. @AlfredoDelgado

Comment: Just create keys with invented values, should not be a problem.

Comment: @Teemu Great way to test code, thanks. At least I know problem does not occur from this part. I guess I will try to use localhost and try with that.